# invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the error "invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*'" generated from this code.
Is the argument 'const int *b' causing the error? Thank you for your advice.

```
int add(int *a, const int *b)
{
    return(*a + *b);
}

int main()
{
    const int x = 1, y = 2;
    cout << add(&x, &y) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It’s the “a” argument, not “b”. The error is converting *from* const *to* without-const, per the message.

Comment: This is C 101, why not read a good book on the languages.

Comment: Passing an `int const*` argument to a function's `int*` parameter is a square peg in a round hole.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `x` is a `const int` so when you take its address like this: `&x`, you get a `const int *`. However, the parameter `a` is an `int *`. You are not allowed to bind a (pointer to non-const) to a (pointer to const), as you might accidentally change the pointed at object.

So the fix in this case would be to make the parameter `a` to be a `const int *` like `b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int add(const int *a, const int *b)
{
 return(*a + *b);
}
```

Your parameters were slightly off.Since you declared a as a const int in main and then used int as a parameter.